# forEach loop for array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array of strings. I would like to fill the strings into an empty string variable using forEach loop. In console I can print out (l and r simultaneosly).I would like to get each values printed into the filltext once. I dont want to join the strings. What am I doing wrong ?

```js
ch_labels = ['l', 'r'];

let ch = '';

let _ch_text = this.ch_labels.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log('channel names:', value);
  ch = value;
});

this.canvas.fillText(ch, 0, 0, 0);

console.log('names', ch);
```

Comment: Use `ch += value`. Every assignation replace the previous stored value otherwise.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why not `ch_labels.join('')`?

Comment: no i dont want to concatenate the string..I want to fill 'l' and 'r' each time once in the variable 'ch'

Comment: you will end up with the very last value in the `ch`. nothing more

Comment: try to re-phrase what exactly do you want to achieve...

Comment: @cantona_7 Then put the `console.log(...)` inside the `forEach()`. Otherwise you are printing the latest value assigned to that variable.

Comment: @spirit is it possible to acheive ch = l and in next iteration ch = r

Comment: So, `console.log(ch)` inside the loop below the `ch = value;` line?

Comment: @cantona_7 yup, you are already doing it ;) really, it's totally unclear what are you want to get as the result

Comment: @spirit I just rephrased and added few more details

Comment: @cantona_7 check my answer. is that's what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
ch_labels = ['l', 'r'];

ch_labels.forEach(function(value, index) {
  console.log('channel names:', value);
  this.canvas.fillText(value, 0, index * 30);
});
```

it will draw your channels one beneath other

Comment: `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation`. I am getting the following error though

Comment: just try to remove it :) also try to adopt the code to your specific case... I've posted the snippet so you can get the idea. don't blindly copy/paste it

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected output, you need to concat the value to your `ch` variable instead of defining the value, like this:

```
ch += value;
```

Also, note that you can't write to canvas directly. `canvas.fillText` will be undefined. Use `context` instead of `canvas`.

So, your code would be:

```js
canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

ch_labels = ['l', 'r'];

let ch = '';

this.ch_labels.forEach(function(value,index) {
  console.log('channel names:', value);
  this.context.fillText(ch, (index+1)*30, 10 );
  ch += value;
});

console.log('names', ch);
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: I dont want to join or concat the strings. I would like to print out 'l' and 'r' one time each in ch

Comment: @cantona_7 I saw your edit and came to edit my answer. Does it solve your issue now?

Comment: just move another channel to a different coordinates, @k3llydev ;) no needs for concatenation

Answer (score 0):

```js
ch_labels = ['l', 'r'];

let ch = '';

let _ch_text = this.ch_labels.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log('channel names:', value);
  ch += value;
});

console.log('names', ch);
```

the problem is that you were re assigning the value, you could use ch = ch + value or the shorten way ch += value